# How to create dynamic name and callback function based on number of added row

Tags: javascript

I have the form below

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="">
        <table id="dateTable">
        <tr>
            <td>


<input type="text" name="date[]" value="" style="width: 25px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="date[]" value="" style="width: 25px;">
                <input type="text" name="month[]" value="" style="width: 25px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="month[]" value="" style="width: 25px;">
                <input type="text" name="year[]" value="" style="width: 40px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="year[]" value="" style="width: 40px;">
                <button onClick="cal_date_1.showCalendar('cal_date_1'); return false;">
                    <img src="php/kantoor/templates/default/images/agenda.gif">
                </button>
                <div id="cal_date_1" class="cal_date"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="td_formfield_text"><img src="php/kantoor/templates/default/images/plus.gif" onclick="addRow();" title="Add" alt="Toevoegen prijs buiten pakket"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I click on button it show the calendar. Choose one date it will set to date, month, year input with the javascript below

```
var date = document.form1.elements["date[]"];
var month = document.form1.elements["month[]"];
var year = document.form1.elements["year[]"];

var cal_date_1 = new CalendarPopup( "cal_date_1", 0, 0);
cal_date_1.setReturnFunction( "cal_date_change_1" );
cal_date_1.setWeekStartDay(1);

function cal_date_change_1( y, m, d ) {
   date[0].value = LZ(d);
   month[0].value = LZ(m);
   year[0].value = LZ(y);
}
```

When I click on the plus image to add more row it will run the function

```
function addRow() {
    var dateTable = document.getElementById("dateTable");
    var noRow = dateTable.rows.length;
    dateTable.insertRow(-1);
    tr = dateTable.rows[noRow];
    tr.insertCell(-1);
    td = tr.cells[0];

    dateInput = document.createElement("input");
    dateInput.type = "text";
    dateInput.name = "date[]";
    dateInput.style.width = 25;

    monthInput = document.createElement("input");
    monthInput.type = "text";
    monthInput.name = "month[]";
    monthInput.style.width = 25;

    yearInput = document.createElement("input");
    yearInput.type = "text";
    yearInput.name = "year[]";
    yearInput.style.width = 40;

    td.appendChild(dateInput);
    td.appendChild(monthInput);
    td.appendChild(yearInput);

    dateButton = document.createElement("button");
    dateButton.setAttribute("id", "datum_bewerken_button_1");

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "php/kantoor/templates/default/images/agenda.gif";
    img.style.width = 16;
    img.style.height = 15;
    img.style.border = 0;

    dateButton.appendChild(img);
    td.appendChild(dateButton);

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "cal_date_" + noRow);

    for (var i = 2; i <= noRow; i++) {
        dateButton.onclick = function () {
            window['cal_date_'+i].showCalendar('cal_date_' + noRow);
            return false;
        }

        window['cal_date_'+i] = new CalendarPopup( "cal_date_" + i, 0, 0);
        window['cal_date_'+i].setReturnFunction("cal_date_change_" + i);
        window['cal_date_'+i].setWeekStartDay( 1 );
    }

}
```

I don't know how to set window['cal_date_'+i].showCalendar('cal_date_' + noRow); this code don't work and how to create callback function for window['cal_date_'+i].setReturnFunction("cal_date_change_" + i);

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I've understood you question correctly, I would advise you to have a look at .addEventListener - the difference between adding the handler inline, in the HTML, and by using this function in javascript, is that the called event knows which element caused it to be fired. This element I mention is always accessed via the `this` keyword. That means you don't have to have a new callback function for each newly added item of content. Here's a fiddle that illustrates the principle: http://jsfiddle.net/jxvGj/

Comment: Thanks enhzflep for answer my question. However, on each row there are a calendar button and three input fields: date, month, year. When click on calendar button the calendar will appear, choose the date on calendar, this date will assign to input fields (date,  month, year). When adding more rows, this function will repeat on each row.

Comment: You're welcome Meo. I'm sorry, I don't understand the intention of your question enough to offer a better suggestion.